# Can I edit my flag?

Tags: support, flags

Sometimes when I flag a question or an answer, I get the feeling that I choose the wrong flag reason.  It's not that I didn't take care before selecting, but sometime I can't decide between one of two choices

The question is as in the title:
**Is it possible to go back to the flag and change the reason?**  There is nothing like this in the popped up interface.

Comment: You can submit new flag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple answer is No. You can not edit your flag.

Flags are taken very seriously so always flag when you are very much sure about of what you are flagging.

Decline flags decreases your flag counts and when it is 0 you may never again be able to flag again.

Answer (score 4):

No, once a flag has been submitted it is not editable or revocable and will remain in the queue in its original state until it is handled by a moderator (or in some cases the community).